# How to start over source control on a project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

unfortunately I messed up the source control on one of my project in Xcode, I'm not able to merge branches as it gives incompatibility issues, so I was thinking to get a rid of it and start over with a new fresh source control.

How can I do this?
I basically want to have a new source control for this project, as if I just started to write it, I don't need to keep track of previous history, but I want to be able to do it from now on.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the .git folder and then `git init` to create a new repository.

Comment: Thanks. Is this through terminal? Is this a per project solution or it would apply to all my projects?

Comment: I understand the .git folder is within my project folder. I can access and delete it through finder, but git init seems a terminal command, should I type it within the project folder then?

Comment: Deleting the .git folder within a project only applies to the repository for that project. And yes it is a terminal command, although you can use a GUI git program to create a new repository